# C++ stoll throws out of range exception when hex representing minus value is passsed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, hex

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and I'm trying to convert string  writen in hex format representing minus value to long long using stoll but I get  out of range exception. Do you know why?

e.g. 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFA7E which is -1410 decimal

example code:

```
std::string s = "0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFA7E";
size_t pos;
auto result = std::stoll(s, &pos, 16);
```

Comment: Freedom is slavery. Ownership is theft. 15 is -1.

Answer (score 2):

Just because unsigned arithmetic (which you're not even using here) wraps around doesn't mean that 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFA7E is -1410 decimal. It's not.

It's a (very large) positive number in any base: by my calculations, 18,446,744,073,709,550,000.

That cannot be handled by a function that works in signed 64-bit types, because the maximum value of a signed 64-bit type is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

**Since `size_t` is an *unsigned* 64-bit type, and you need to read a value that will only fit into an *unsigned* 64-bit type, use the function that does that thing: [`strtoull`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul).**

Comment: Thank you for your answer but honestly I do not get everything.  0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFA7E is -1410 in two’s complement for 64bit long number.  
Why this stoll function treat this as unsigned? If I would like it to be like this I would use stoull function.

Comment: @KrzysztofKupka: _"Why this stoll function treat this as unsigned?"_ It doesn't. It treats it as signed. It's a signed, _positive_ number. And, as signed, it's out of range, just like the exception says. You _need_ to treat it as unsigned, so that it will be in range, and you can do that because you're about to put it into an unsigned variable anyway.

Comment: @KrzysztofKupka: _"0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFA7E is -1410 in two’s complement for 64bit long number"_ This is a misstatement. -0x582 is -1410. 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFA7E is 18446744073709550000. You're conflating value and representation. `strtoll` does not read bit patterns; it reads _numbers_. Two's complement doesn't have anything to do with it.